# Disable index files with SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, http, server, directoryindex

By default, SimpleHTTPServer uses `index.html` as a index file, I would like to disable them and always show a directory index.

How can I do that? The [document here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) says nothing about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should be overwriting the `send_head` method

Simply disable the following lines

```
        for index in "index.html", "index.htm":
            index = os.path.join(path, index)
            if os.path.exists(index):
                path = index
                break
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Simple way :

Rename the index file to anything else

#### A more complicated Approach :

You would have to override the *translate_path* method of **SimpleHTTPRequestHandler** with something like this:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
server_address = ("", 8888)
PUBLIC_RESOURCE_PREFIX = '/public'
PUBLIC_DIRECTORY = '/path/to/protected/public'

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def translate_path(self, path):
        if self.path.startswith(PUBLIC_RESOURCE_PREFIX):
            if self.path == PUBLIC_RESOURCE_PREFIX or self.path == PUBLIC_RESOURCE_PREFIX + '/':
                return PUBLIC_DIRECTORY + path[len(PUBLIC_RESOURCE_PREFIX):]
        else:
            return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.translate_path(self, path)

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, MyRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```